# Why am I seeing "Error: length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE" with ddply?

Tags: r, plyr, summary

I have a data frame, say payroll, like:

```
payroll <- read.table(text="
AgencyName          Rate             PayBasis     Status    NumRate
HousingAuthority    $26,843.00   Annual           Full-Time 26843.00
HousingAuthority    $14,970.00   ProratedAnnual   Part-Time 14970.00
HousingAuthority    $26,843.00   Annual           Full-Time 26843.00
HousingAuthority    $14,970.00   ProratedAnnual   Part-Time 14970.00
HousingAuthority    $13.50           Hourly           Part-Time 13.50
HousingAuthority    $14,970.00   ProratedAnnual   Part-Time 14970.00
HousingAuthority    $26,843.00   Annual           Full-Time 26843.00", header = TRUE)
```

The "NumRate" is actually numeric:

```
payroll$NumRate <- as.numeric(payroll$NumRate)
```

And I'd like to get a know the max, min and mean salaries by PayBasis. I expect this to work:

```
ddply(payroll, "PayBasis", summarize)
```

But instead I'm getting an error: `Error: length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because you've mistaken `summarize` for `summary` (which won't work like you expect in this context). You probably wanted:

```
ddply(payroll, "PayBasis", summarize,mx = max(NumRate),mn = min(NumRate),avg = mean(NumRate))
        PayBasis      mx      mn     avg
1         Annual 26843.0 26843.0 26843.0
2         Hourly    13.5    13.5    13.5
3 ProratedAnnual 14970.0 14970.0 14970.0
```

And be sure to look more carefully at the examples in `?summarize` and `?ddply`.

Answer (score 1):

It could also be the `plyr` library. Try either not to load it, or, if you need it be careful whether you load it before or after other libraries such as `dplyr`, or `tidyverse` which automatically fires up the `dplyr`

Answer (score 0):

to make sure you are using the correct command use `dplyr::summarize`. As you can guess there are a lot of libraries that uses "summarizes" command