# Error: length(cols) > 0 is not TRUE on SparkR agg function

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I try to group a dataframe by a certain column:

```
>SparkR::agg(SparkR::groupBy(df, "column_1"))
```

Why do I get the following error:

```
Error: length(cols) > 0 is not TRUE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this kind of error ([see also this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053764/why-am-i-seeing-error-lengthrows-1-is-not-true-with-ddply)) relates to the parameters provided to the function (here: agg). I missed specifying the output column:

```
SparkR::agg(SparkR::groupBy(df, "column_1"), "column_1")
```